# Use JDBC to check the memory(RAM) used in queries

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to check the memory used when executing queries. I already have JDBC connected to my database in MYSQL. And I also know how to execute the queries. But I do not know how to check the memory used in executing queries. This is to make comparison of memory and time. I'm using NetBeans.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(long id)` to get the approx. amount of bytes used by the thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadAllocatedBytes(long)

When Your JDBC connection, statement , & result set stuffs are executed by thread, you can get the approx. amount of memory used by thread by providing the thread id.

Refer- [Will ThreadMXBean#getThreadAllocatedBytes return size of allocated memory or objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176593/will-threadmxbeangetthreadallocatedbytes-return-size-of-allocated-memory-or-obj)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the memory usage in the database server (through JDBC), you can't. Ask the DBA about that.

If it's for your app or for your application server, then you can use [Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory()) to get the memory usage before and after the database/JDBC call.

Even better, you can do it remotely using JMX. The most basic use of JConsole can help you there.

Comment: Thanks, what i need is the Runtime. But freeMemory() returns the amount of free memory, and i need the memory usage during the query. Do you know what i need?